# How to modify TestNG report?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, eclipse

[image]

I have generated a test suite and  run the testng.xml file and default report is generated accordingly.

I want to modify default generated report. I want to display one column which shows the pass and fail result for each testcase. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In package explorer->test-output->right click on emailable-report.html  file and open with texteditor. change name by default(Parameter#1) to "Name"

Comment: Please check after re-run of project.

Comment: I have check it's display correct

Comment: Please re-run project with testng.xml and refresh folder. After that open the file from test-output folder. I am not able to find parameter name as you say.

Comment: ya that's right.i have also check after open file from test-output it's change

Comment: Because every testng run the folder files get refreshed and reload as previous default configuration. So this is not appropriate way to do so.

Comment: then what is solution for that

Comment: Use log4j for getting all system logs and send it to mail as per my given answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50012/discussion-between-rutvi-soni-and-sagar007).

Answer (score 1):

There are several customized report tools available in market. Also you can use some API like [ExtentReport](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/) which is also useful and most of the functionality is given by default.

Lets come to question, Please [refer this link](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testng-customize-emailable-html-report-example). Here you can add some lines of java code to add or remove the result of TestNG report.

**As per my practical example TestNG by default shows parameter as given in email-able Html report. I have run project from testng.xml** Here file is attached.

[image]

**As you want to print whole data regarding the actions and inputs, You can also use [Log4J](http://www.guru99.com/tutorial-on-log4j-and-logexpert-with-selenium.html). It would create separate file for logging this type of details with larger configuration.**

Comment: Hello I want to change only parameter name which is display by default. i have try to change from html file but did not change

Comment: Let me see further.

Comment: What is parameter name is here?

Comment: Here I want to change parameter#1 to username .

Comment: Hi I had run project with parameter and it is running fine and shows parameter name. Can you please tell from where you run testng ? from textng.xml or from direct class?

Comment: for just checking i am run login.java class file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49965/discussion-between-sagar007-and-rutvi-soni).

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to override the report creation by creating your own [implementation of IReporter interface](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_custom_reporter.htm):

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.IReporter;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

public class CustomReporter implements IReporter{
    @Override
    public void generateReport(List xmlSuites, List suites,
        String outputDirectory) {
        // Iterating over each suite included in the test
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            // Following code gets the suite name
            String suiteName = suite.getName();
        // Getting the results for the said suite
        Map suiteResults = suite.getResults();
        for (ISuiteResult sr : suiteResults.values()) {
            ITestContext tc = sr.getTestContext();
            System.out.println("Passed tests for suite '" + suiteName +
                 "' is:" + tc.getPassedTests().getAllResults().size());
            System.out.println("Failed tests for suite '" + suiteName +
                 "' is:" + tc.getFailedTests().getAllResults().size());
            System.out.println("Skipped tests for suite '" + suiteName +
                 "' is:" + tc.getSkippedTests().getAllResults().size());
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try working with the surefire plugin. This is a better option which works fine with TestNG. Also easy to integrate with Jenkins.

http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/